# Django query __startswith is not case sensitive

Tags: django, django-views

I have been testing user searching with sorted results and I found this strange behavior

```
>>> User.objects.filter(username__istartswith="AbC")
<QuerySet [<User: AbC>, <User: AbCuuu>, <User: abc>, <User: abcuuu>]>
>>> User.objects.filter(username__startswith="AbC")
<QuerySet [<User: AbC>, <User: AbCuuu>, <User: abc>, <User: abcuuu>]>
```

Shouldn't __startswith only have 2 of those results?
I need to actually search with case sensitivity, how do I do that?

I expect __startswith to be case sensitive and __istartswith to be case insensitive, but both return the same, case insensitive QuerySet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are most likely using SQLite, where `startswith` will return the same result as `istartswith`, due to lack of case sensive `LIKE` (see text in bold at the bottom):

> #### startswith
>
> Case-sensitive starts-with.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> Entry.objects.filter(headline__startswith='Lennon')
> ```
>
> SQL equivalent:
>
> ```
> SELECT ... WHERE headline LIKE 'Lennon%';
> ```
>
> **SQLite doesn’t support case-sensitive `LIKE` statements; `startswith` acts like `istartswith` for SQLite.**

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#startswith

Comment: If I need case sensitive filtering, is it worth it to switch to a different database? I'm thinking MySQL, does it have the desired functionality and would it introduce any other weirdness?

Comment: @donotread123 Generally I would consider SQLite suitable for development purpose but with certain limitations that you have encountered. For production databases, I would use a proper database like PostgreSQL.